# Cloud Page Journey Receives Email Send Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, cloudpage

I have a CloudPage that is populating a Journey when people sign up to simply send them an email. The problem is that when they fillout the form since they are not a member of our All Subscribers list they are being errored out with this message.

Failed - Email.JourneyBuilder.Activities.EmailActivity.EmailAddress: Error binging data bound member

I tried re configuring the data extension to make sure the field type was set to email, as well as having the data extension the CloudPage drops into set as sendable. I've also made sure I was sending into a publication list as apposed to All Subscribers, but I am still running into these errors. I have other Journeys running that can execute email sends but this is the only CloudPage Journey we have running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the Default Email Address in your journey settings? Or change your Channel Address Order in Contact Builder?

In order for you to start sending to contacts who don't already exist on your All Subscribers list, into an email channel Journey Builder Interaction you'll need to configure a new Attribute Group.

Create a new Attribute Group in Contact Builder using Data Designer. Then check your journey settings and select the attribute for Default Email Address.

Use Contact Configuration to specify how Contact Builder handles new contact information. This information can result from imported contacts or from activities and interactions between the contact and other Marketing Cloud apps.

The Channel Address Order in Contact Configuration determines which channel address field takes precedence over another for all send activities. For example, if a contact uses three different email addresses, determine which email address to use over the other addresses unless otherwise specified.

Contacts Configuration
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_configure_contacts.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Attribute Group Creation
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_create_attribute_group.htm&type=5

Contact Model Best Practices
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232652&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: I can't believe I didn't double check my default Journey email address that was the change needed!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out!